# $f\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ with $(\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n)\ni||\dot{\mathcal{P}_n}||\to 0.$. Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}S(f;\dot{\mathcal{P}_n})=\int_a^b f$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration

Sorry for the wonky title -- I had to really condense the exercise to fit all the LaTeX code in! Anyways, I am working on Exercise 7.1.3 from [Lesson 7.1](https://www.geneseo.edu/%7Eaguilar/public/notes/Real-Analysis-HTML/ch7-riemann-integration.html) in Real Analysis by Cesar O. Aguilar. The exercise says:

> If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $(\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n)$ is a sequence of tagged partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n||\to 0$ prove that $$ \int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty}S(f;\dot{\mathcal{P}_n}).$$

I'm wondering if my attempt below is correct. I'm particularly unsure about my choice of $\delta_1$ and $\delta$.

**Proof:** Since $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n||\to 0,$ given $\delta_1>0,$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N,$ we have that $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n||<\delta_1.$ Now suppose $\epsilon>0$. Then since $f\in\mathcal{R}[a,b],$ given any tagged partition $\dot{\mathcal{P}}$ of $[a,b],$ there exists some $\delta_2>0$ such that if $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}||<\delta_2$, then $\left|S(f;\mathcal{P})-\int_a^b f\right|<\epsilon$. Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2).$ Then if $n\geq N$ and $||\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n||<\delta,$ we have that $\left|S(f;\dot{\mathcal{P}}_n)-\int_a^b f\right|<\epsilon.$ Therefore, $$ \int_a^b f=\lim_{n\to\infty}S(f;\dot{\mathcal{P}_n}).$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: I am unsure what the definition of a tagged partition is. If it just means a partition in the usual sense, i.e., $[a,b]=\cup_{k=0,m} [a_k,b_k]$, then you don't really need $\delta_1$. What I mean by this is if you fix $\varepsilon>0$, since $f$ is integrable, there will be some $\delta$ such that any partition with mesh size at most $\delta$ will be $\varepsilon$ close to the integral. Now all you need is a $N$ large enough so that the mesh size of the $P_n$ goes below $\delta$, which is guaranteed by the assumption.

Comment: @AnCar Suppose $\mathcal{P}=\{[x_{k-1},x_k]\}_{k=1}^n$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. Then given $t_k\in[x_{k-1},x_k]=I_k$, we say that $t_k$ is a *tag* or *sample* of $I_k$. Then the *tagged partition* or *sampled partition* of $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of ordered pairs $\dot{\mathcal{P}}=\{[x_{k-1},x_k],t_k\}_{k=1}^n$. That makes sense about not needing $\delta_1$ -- that's what I was wondering.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's the partition plus the samples. Hmm, don't remember seeing that referred to as a tagged partition before. But hey, it's been a while since my undergrad :)

Comment: Yes pretty much! I remember seeing it referred to as a tagged partition in the Bartle and Sherbert book as well. I guess people call it different things 